# How can I export database objects in PL/SQL the same way toad does?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper, toad

I am switching from toad to pl/sql developer and want to take backups of the schema. In toad, I select Database->Export->Generate Schema Script and there is tab called object types and I can select the objects I want to have.

Does anyone how to do this in pl/sql developer? I got as far as Tools->Export User Objects..
I am looking at the list and it doesn't have everything that toad has, and there is nowhere I can find to select which objects I want. For example, the jobs are not in the user objects (and the user owns them).

I have version 8.0.4.1514. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You might have better luck with this question over on [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). It's more of a database administration type question than it is programming, and it's related to backups, which makes it on-topic there according to their help center.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Everyone is so helpful here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PL/SQL Developer, I don't know the solution. Also 8.0.4 is really outdated. I don't have 8.0.4 available to check it on anymore, but maybe that release already had the package dbms_metadata. If so, use something like:

```
  l_clob   clob;
  l_return varchar2(240);
begin
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'DEFAULT', true);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'STORAGE', false);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'TABLESPACE', false);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'REF_CONSTRAINTS', false);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'CONSTRAINTS', false);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PARTITIONING', false);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SIZE_BYTE_KEYWORD', true);
  begin
    l_clob   := dbms_metadata.get_ddl(p_object_type, p_object_name, p_owner);
    ...
```

When not, you might want to consider Oracle import/export (the old one with 8.0.4, not data pump). Using 'imp show=yes' I think to remember you can print all DDL and using 'log=xxx' spool it to a text file.

Last alternative is querying the data dictionary and constructing the statements yourself, but I don't have the code for it anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the console. I will look at trying to get a new version of sql developer. Thank you for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: For import/export or the queries, you don't need access to the console. The old imp/exp can run reliably across SQL*Net, so if you can connect using SQL Developer, you can run exp/imp too. If not available on your PC, please install the client with administration software. During the client installation that is the option that takes 500 MB of storage :-)